# What does "do more of late" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence below:

> The Republican presidential debate earned Fox News record ratings, and despite the clash, no outlet **has done more of** late to present Donald Trump as a serious thinker than Fox.

What does *do more of* in the last clause mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence *of* is not a piece of any sort of 'phrasal' ('particle', 'preposition') verb construction. Together with its object *more* it forms a preposition phrase locating the clause in time.

> of late = lately, recently

You can move it to the front of the clause if you like:

> Of late, no outlet has done more to present Donald Trump as a serious thinker.

That is, other outlets have done less than Fox to present Donald Trump as a serious thinker.